# TFS2012: Can we modify web access board filters?

Tags: tfs

Can we add/modify the filter of the boards:

- **Work/Backlog/product backlog/board**(*the stories/backlogitems*)
- Should be able to filter the Iterations/Sprints
- **Work/board**(*tasks*)
- Should be able to change the Areapath filtering

Is there any way to change the default filter and/or add quick filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this post, you can't really amend the underlying
query for the task board:
[How do I change the underlying query for the task board (and backlog board) on TFS Preview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/a0e6d48e-eda7-4dc4-95ac-bd1f5ab0fd29/)

Although as mentioned the tags in TFS 2012 Update 2 can help.

However we achieved something similar to what you are
asking by creating a team per product.

- In the web control panel for your team project, create teams (and area paths) for
  each product you are interested in.
- In the control panel, for each of these teams, you can set which 
  iterations are associated with them.  So for a particular team, 
  you associate only the iterations you are interested in for that 
  product.

You are then able to switch between teams via a drop-down at the
top-left in the TFS web interface (you will need to use Browse All
originally.)

See [Multiple Teams with Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 & Visual Studio Scrum V2.0](http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/colinbird/2012/11/19/MultipleTeamsWithMicrosoftTeamFoundationServer2012VisualStudioScrumV20.aspx) for a good reference for this.

Answer (score 0):

The [Work Item Tagging](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2013/jan-30/#work%20item%20tagging)  feature in [TFS 2012 Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update) can help.

Other than that, you can write your own [plugin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/serkani/archive/2012/06/22/work-item-custom-control-development-in-tf-web-access-2012-development.aspx).

Comment: We are running Update 2. Thanks for the  tagging suggestion, but not everything is stored as tags. Thanks for the blog link!